Preventing Padding Oracle Attacks in Thruk by Implementing GCM Encryption
I'm running the Thruk monitoring interface, and I'm concerned about the potential for padding oracle attacks. Currently, Thruk uses CBC mode for encryption, which is vulnerable to these types of attacks. I'd like to improve the security by implementing GCM (Galois/Counter Mode) encryption instead.
To achieve this, I need to add custom decrypt and encrypt methods in the Thruk/Utils/Crypt.pm file. However, I'm worried that this file might be overwritten during future Thruk updates, which would undo my changes.
Question: What is the recommended folder location where I should place my custom Crypt.pm file to ensure it is not overwritten during Thruk upgrades?
The goal is to implement the more secure GCM encryption without having to worry about my changes being lost during Thruk updates. I want to make sure I'm following the best practices for Thruk customization.
Any guidance on the appropriate directory structure and configuration steps would be greatly appreciated. I want to make sure I'm addressing the padding oracle vulnerability properly while also maintaining the ability to upgrade Thruk in the future.

If you want to improve Thruk and its security, everyone can profit from it if you do it in the upstream repository: https://github.com/sni/Thruk.

i second that, please raise an issue.  Improving it directly at upstream is the easiest way to retain maintainability.
